# How to calculate Lipschitz constant?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

How can I calculate a Lipschitz constant for a 2-dimensional real-valued $C^{\infty}$ function with bounded derivatives?

Comment: use Taylor's theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the mean value theorem
$$
f(x)-f(y)=\nabla f(\xi)\cdot(x-y)
$$
for some $\xi$ in the segment joining $x$ and $y$. Since $f$ has bounded partial derivatives, there is an $M>0$ such that $|\nabla(x)|\le M$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Then
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\le M\,|x-y|.
$$
($|z|$ is the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of $z=(z_1,z_2)$.)